# signal 11 in a linux shell remote site. How can I troubleshoot

Tags: linux, supercomputers

I'm a bio major only recently doing major coding for research stuff. Our campus in order to support research has an on campus supercomputer for researcher use. I work remotely from this supercomputer and it uses a linux shell to access it and submit jobs. I'm writing a job submission script for the alignment of a lot of genomes using a program installed on the computer called Mauve. Now I've run a job on Mauve fine before and have altered the script from that job to fit this job. Only this time I keep getting this error

```
Storing raw sequence at
/scratch/addiseg/Elizabethkingia_clonalframe/rawseq16360.000
Sequence loaded successfully.
GCA_000689515.1_E27107v1_PRJEB5243_genomic.fna 4032057 base pairs.
Storing raw sequence at 
/scratch/addiseg/Elizabethkingia_clonalframe/rawseq16360.001
Sequence loaded successfully.
e.anophelisGCA_000496055.1_NUH11_genomic.fna 4091484 base pairs.
Caught signal 11
Cleaning up and exiting!
Temporary files deleted.
```

So I've got no idea how to troubleshoot this. I'm so sorry if this is super basic and wasting time but I don't know how to troubleshoot this at a remote site. All possible solutions I've seen so far require me to access the hardware or software neither of which I can control.
My current submission script is this.

```
module load mauve 
progressiveMauve --output=8elizabethkingia-alignment.etc.xmfa --output-guide-tree=8.elizabethkingia-alignment.etc.tree --backbone-output=8.elizabethkingia-alignment.etc.backbone --island-gap-size=100 e.anophelisGCA_000331815.1_ASM33181v1_genomicR26.fna GCA_000689515.1_E27107v1_PRJEB5243_genomic.fna e.anophelisGCA_000496055.1_NUH11_genomic.fna GCA_001596175.1_ASM159617v1_genomicsrr3240400.fna e.meningoseptica502GCA_000447375.1_C874_spades_genomic.fna e.meningoGCA_000367325.1_ASM36732v1_genomicatcc13253.fna e.anophelisGCA_001050935.1_ASM105093v1_genomicPW2809.fna e.anophelisGCA_000495935.1_NUHP1_genomic.fna
```

Comment: If the remote code isn't compiled with debug symbols, or you don't have permissions to run it in a debugger, you're going to need to get assistance from someone else.

Comment: ...you can also see about configuring the system to store a core dump, if ulimit settings &c. allow, and analyze that core dump, but without a debug build it's still not very usable/helpful. Short form: Talk to the people who wrote and maintain the software.

Comment: ...I also removed the bash tag: just because you're starting a program from a shell doesn't mean it's a shell-related question, unless that program is actually written as a shell script.

Comment: The program probably runs out of memory without noticing it. The only workaround you could try is: start the program for every sequence, but separately. You might need to create a script to accomplish this. (it looks like the program does a simple {input,process,output} loop for every sequence)